# How to open a pop-up window using Ajax Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am developing a website, as i have to display a product details in a pop-up window, when a product is clicked. i want to open that pop-up window in secure manner so that the address bar in the pop-up window can be hided. can i use ajax control to open the pop-up window., if that possible, can anyone please help me.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal popup from ajax control toolkit. Follow the [link](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) for more details and working examples. Other than this there are JavaScript libraries like [Thick Box](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), [Light Box](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/), [Submodal](http://code.google.com/p/submodal/). These can also be used to show the page/data in popup windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example and use according to your requirement

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Edit-Update-Records-in-GridView-using-Modal-Popup-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: thanks for reply. if suppose i need to open a website page in pop-up window using ajax. then what i should do for it...thanks once again...